# Codecademy - Interactive Website: Disable the button 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't find the issue. It's saying:

> Oops, try again. Remember to disable the Post button after posting a new message

Update: It turns out there was a little buggy on Codecademy,I resubmitted the code and it worked.

```
var main = function() {
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        var post = $('.status-box').val();
        $('<li>').text(post).prependTo('.posts');
        $('.status-box').val('');
        $('.counter').text('140');
        $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
    });

    $('.status-box').keyup(function() {
        var postLength = $(this).val().length;
        var charactersLeft = 140 - postLength;
        $('.counter').text(charactersLeft);

        if(charactersLeft < 0) {
            $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
        }
        else if(charactersLeft == 140) {
            $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
        }
        else { 
            $('.btn').removeClass('disabled');
        }
    });
             $('.btn').addClass('disabled');

            $(document).ready(main);
            }
```

Comment: `$('.btn').addClass('disabled').prop('disabled', true')` in `btn` click handler

Comment: Could you please provide the codecademy link of the above exercise?

Comment: Sure.  https://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-hk5qh/0/8?content_from=make-an-interactive-website%3Ajquery-dom-manipulation

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/37rno2nq/) is an example:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {$(this).attr("disabled", true);})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forgetting to close the function braces. After the last line there should be a closing brace and semicolon `};` like this:

```
var main = function() {
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        var post = $('.status-box').val();
        $('<li>').text(post).prependTo('.posts');
        $('.status-box').val('');
        $('.counter').text('140');
        $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
    });

    $('.status-box').keyup(function() {
        var postLength = $(this).val().length;
        var charactersLeft = 140 - postLength;
        $('.counter').text(charactersLeft);

        if(charactersLeft < 0) {
            $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
        }
        else if(charactersLeft == 140) {
            $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
        }
        else { 
            $('.btn').removeClass('disabled');
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Hmm.. I didn't forget, I think I didn't paste the whole code at the first time. I edited my code. Also,Thank you:)